# How to drop the last row of a table?

Tags: typescript, office-scripts

I am trying to drop the last 2 rows of all the tables in my worksheet.

To do so, I have been using this basic sequence of code :

```
let tables = workbook.getTables();
for (let table of tables) {
            let rowCount = table.getRangeBetweenHeaderAndTotal().getRowCount();
            table.deleteRowsAt(rowCount - 1);
            table.deleteRowsAt(rowCount - 2);
```

However it looks like I am not using deleteRowsAt as expected I keep outputing

```
Table deleteRowsAt: The argument is invalid, is missing or has an invalid format.
```

Would anybody know more about how I may sort this out please ?

I have played around with the iterations of the function but no luck. I have also tried the function delete() but it does not actually remove the row from the table, it just erases the content.

Thanks in advance,
Nicolas.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is nearly complete. The only issue is that the `deleteRowsAt` method requires two parameters, and the second one is currently missing.

```js
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
  let tables = workbook.getTables();
  for (let table of tables) {
    let rowCount = table.getRangeBetweenHeaderAndTotal().getRowCount();
    table.deleteRowsAt(rowCount - 2, 2);
  }
}
```

Comment: Damn, it was very easy! Thanks for your quick feedback, the documentation got me confused...